# Why can't you call functions declared inside parenthesis?

Tags: javascript

As far as I can tell, JS is function scoped and not block scoped, meaning objects declared inside (parenthesis) do not create a different execution context. However:

```
$('#firstBtn').click(function first() {
    console.log("first activated");
});

$('#secondBtn').click(function() {
    console.log("second activated");
    first();
});
```

Returns `Reference Error function is undefined`. The function `first` is being declared inside a parenthesis, so technically it should be available to other functions that call it from the scope it was declared at.

But this works:

```
var callDat = $('#firstBtn').click(function first() {
    console.log("first activated");
});

$('#secondBtn').click(function() {
    console.log("second activated");
    callDat.first();
});
```

My assumption is that since objects are functions, declaring a function inside an object can count as declared inside a different function scope even without curly braces. I however wish for a definitive answer on this.

Comment: In `function first() {` `first` is the alias created to call the function from itself. `first` is not accessible from outside of `first`.

Comment: Have a look at [Named function expressions demystified](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/). Named function expression !== function declaration. For the second example you jump to the completely wrong conclusion.

Comment: My bad, the second example does not work. However I had this question in mind before I came up with my "solution" so I think it should not be deleted, though maybe edited so as to not distract further readers from my original inquiry?

Comment: So, what is the actual question?

Comment: @Jamiec why is the function not available even though its not within curly braces.

Comment: All of them are *function expressions*. To create a function and put it in the current scope, you use *function declarations*. You can only determine if something is a function declaration or a named function expression by looking at the surrounding code: function declarations are statements, but function expressions are expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second example, the `first` you're getting is not the one you've declared above - its the [`jQuery.first`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) method available to all jQuery objects.

This is checkable - clicking "First" and then "Second" below does not output "first activated" from a click to the second button.

```js
var callDat = $('#firstBtn').click(function first() {
    console.log("first activated");
});

$('#secondBtn').click(function() {
    console.log("second activated");
    callDat.first();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="firstBtn">First</button>

<button id="secondBtn">Second</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Returns Reference Error function is undefined. The function first is being declared inside a parenthesis, so technically it should be available to other functions that call it from the scope it was declared at.

No. Function declarations create a variable in the scope they are declared with which has the same name as the function. Function expressions do not, even if they are *named* function expressions. (Named function expressions to create a variable of that name inside their own scope).

Further reading: [JavaScript function declaration syntax: var fn = function() {} vs function fn() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-function-declaration-syntax-var-fn-function-vs-function-fn)

> My assumption is that since objects are functions,

Functions are objects. The reverse is not necessarily true.

> declaring a function inside an object can count as declared inside a different function scope even without curly braces

No, it can't.

Comment: I have read that article and I somewhat understand this. You answer my second example - but what about the first? Both are declared functions.

Comment: @BarAkiva — Neither are function declarations. You have only function expressions.

Answer (score 1):

In first example you actually **do** create a scope - this:

```
$('#firstBtn').click(function first() {
    console.log("first activated");
});
```

is actually this:

```
(function first() {
    console.log("first activated");
})
```

And as such is **not** available to other scopes

Now - if you'll declare it as such:

```
function first() {
    console.log("first activated");
}

$('#firstBtn').click(first);

$('#secondBtn').click(function() {
    console.log("second activated");
    first();
});
```

you won't get the error

Answer (score 0):

It's a "function literal" or "function expression" which only **returns a function as a value**, but does not define it in the surrounding function scope as a variable. It does, however, have its own scope. See my snippet below for something very interesting:

```js
var counter = 0;

// function "b" is acting as a value to be given to "a"
var a = function b() {

  alert(counter);

  counter++;

  // both "b" and "a" are accessible in here
  if(counter < 3) b();

};

a(); // only a is accessible here
```

Because it's not obvious from the syntax, the form...

```
function func() { ... }
```

...may be replaced by the following to be more clear:

```
var func = function() { ... };
```